# scrapy xpath : get all the inner text inside an element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get all the text inside the span tag. But instead of getting 2 elements, I am getting 4.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-7">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;" class="text-black">
        Minimum 2 years of experience developing mobile/web applications using 
        <b>Ionic-3, Ionic-4, AngularJS, Angular.</b>
        <p></p>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;" class="text-black">
        Experience with Agile
        <b>(SCRUM, Kanban)</b>
        <p></p>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My scrapy code to parse HTML is

```
response.xpath(".//div[@class='col-sm-6 col-md-7']//ul/li//span//text()")
```

My expected output is:

```
["Minimum 2 years of experience developing mobile/web applications using Ionic-3, Ionic-4, AngularJS, Angular.","Experience with Agile (SCRUM, Kanban)"]
```

But I am getting this:

```
["Minimum 2 years of experience developing mobile/web applications using", "Ionic-3, Ionic-4, AngularJS, Angular.","Experience with Agile", "(SCRUM, Kanban)"]
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that without joining strings. because "Ionic-3 .." is under another `<b>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It happened because text data separated by `<b>` tags.

In your case following steps needed:

```
data = []
# separately select span tags:
for span_tag in response.xpath(".//div[@class='col-sm-6 col-md-7']//ul/li//span"):
# for each span tag add it's text as single string:
    data.append("".join(span_tag.xpath("//text()").extract()))
```